# Add an offset to sticky top navbar in Foundation

Tags: navigation, zurb-foundation, sticky

I'm using Zurb Foundation 4 and I need to use the topbar navigation.  However, I have two nav bars, one is black and goes 100% of screen width. This one is simple with two links and a search form.  This one should be fixed.

The second one is white maxes out at 980px width and contains 3-4 levels.  There is a masthead in between.

I need both to collapse.

What I want to do is make the second (main) navbar sticky, but instead of sticking to the top of the browser window, I want to give it an offset so that it "sticks" below the black bar.

I can do this in bootstrap, but I can't figure out how to do it in foundation.

The other alternative is to have a single black navbar when collapsed.

I could o that with CSS, but since the main nav is pretty big, I don't want to have it downloaded twice.  I tried appendAround.js but it doesn't work within the topbar.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe this is why I can't get it to work: _http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488813/a-sticky-top-bar-makes-the-page-jump-up-when-scrolling-past-it-with-zurb-foundat?rq=1