# Sticky topbar not working Zurb Foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I read many things against using topbar from Foundation. Like

[A sticky Top Bar makes the page jump up when scrolling past it with Zurb Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488813/a-sticky-top-bar-makes-the-page-jump-up-when-scrolling-past-it-with-zurb-foundat)

and here

https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2005

It is very "flaky" for me. Sometime works and sometime doesn't

This is my code http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/48Tur/1/

I activated it by this right?

```
$(document).foundation().foundation('topbar');
```

Any clue why this one does NOT stick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48Tur/3/). You missed out some `css`

```
.sticky{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
}
.cuisine {
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: Somehow I thought topbar.js supposed to add that. Ops!

Comment: Then, what is the difference between top-bar fixed and sticky class?

Answer (score 2):

add this to your css

```
.sticky{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
}
.cuisines{
    margin-top:50px;
}
```